# Data from thymelaf form not saving properly into db

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm dealing with saving an entity from thymealaf form to database.

---

My current approach.

Thymeleaf form in register.html

```
 <form action="save" th:method="post" th:action="@{save}" th:object="${customer}">
            <input type ="text" th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="First Name" /><br />
            <input type ="text" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Last Name" /><br />
            <input type="email" th:field="*{emailAddress}"  placeholder="Email" /><br />
            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}"  placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <input style="text-align: center" type="submit" value="Register" /> </form>
```

Controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/home")
  public String home(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("customer", new Customer());
    return "register";
  }

  @RequestMapping("save")
  public String save(@ModelAttribute(value = "customer") Customer customer) {
    customerRepository.save(customer);
    return "saved";
  }
```

There is an issue with data binding as you can see in the attached screenshot

[image: database results]

Comment: RequestMapping should be "/save" and th:action="@{/save}"

Comment: It didn't change anything. Actually the button "register" isn't doing anything right now - no data are saved in db

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Just needed to change dependencies from:

```
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
          <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>
```

to

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

**as I can see you did not mention the name in the input field thymelaf binds data using the name
so u have to add a name in the input field as follow**

```
<form action="save" th:method="post" action="save" th:object="${customer}">
            <input type ="text" name="first_name"  placeholder="First Name"  /><br />
            <input type ="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" /><br />
            <input type="email" name="email_address"  placeholder="Email" /><br />
            <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="Password" /><br />
            <input style="text-align: center" type="submit" value="Register" /> </form>
```

**note:- name in the input field is should match with your names from the table**